# React app is not serving static files when running in Docker-Swarm

Tags: reactjs, docker-swarm

I have a React application being served by an NGINX container. The application works fine when deployed using Docker, but when I deploy it with Docker Swarm, the static files are not being loaded in the browser and are showing as 0-byte files. The index.html loads correctly, and I can see the title in the browser tab, but no other resources are loaded.

The Docker Swarm Manager is running on the same server as my NGINX container.

I don't think it's an NGINX issue because I can't curl the static files locally either:

```
root@lb-1:~# curl 10.0.0.2:80/static/js/main.a647b745.js
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

The logs of the container on the worker indicate that the request was successful:

```
10.0.0.2 - - [05/May/2023:03:38:56 +0000] "GET /static/js/main.a647b745.js HTTP/1.1" 200 768663 "-" "curl/7.81.0" "-"
```

Index.html is working fine:

```
root@lb-1:~# curl 10.0.0.2:80
    <!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/><meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/><meta name="description" content="Example"/><link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="./logo192.png"/><link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json"/><title>Example</title><script defer="defer" src="./static/js/main.a647b745.js"></script><link href="./static/css/main.faffc4b4.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id="root"></div></body></html>
```

```
10.0.0.2 - - [05/May/2023:03:57:06 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 661 "-" "curl/7.81.0" "-"
```

It seems like there is an issue with the connection between the manager and the worker. I have already turned off the firewall for the 10.0.0.0/16 IPs.

I'm not sure weather this is normal but i also saw that the worker is running on port 8080 eventhough the manager the service is running on 80. Is this because of the ingress-network managed by docker-swarm?

[image: port for docker service]

[image: port for docker worker]

How can I resolve this issue with static files not being loaded when deploying my React application with Docker Swarm? Any help appriciated.

I have already turned off the firewall for the 10.0.0.0/16 IPs.

Answer (score 0):

So the root cause and solution for this strange behavior is explained here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63405536/1961312

> turns out it was a clash between my local networks subnet and the
> subnet of the automatically created ingress network.